# Jquery .toggle - a way to write it shorter?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm playing around with Jquery and JS for a bit to get the basics and I'm facing the following problem:

I got 5 paragraphs. When i click on a paragraph(vraag) it will show another paragraph(antwoord). Then again, when i press "Antwoord", i has to hide again. Right now i've written a new function for every Vraag/Antwoord. Im looking for a way to write this alot shorter! I've been looking around a bit, and did some brainstorming myself, but i cannot come up with something. The way i wrote it now is very sloppy.

Also, when i press "vraag", then press "antwoord" to hide it again, it will toggle for 3 times. I'm not sure what causes this problem!

Hopefully there is someone who can give me a hand with this, and enlighten me! :)

Thxx!

The code:

```
<hmtl>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#vraag1").click(function(){
                $("#antwoord1").toggle('normal');
                $("#antwoord1").click(function(){
                    $("#antwoord1").toggle('normal');   
                });
            });
            $("#vraag2").click(function(){
                $("#antwoord2").toggle('normal');
                $("#antwoord2").click(function(){
                    $("#antwoord2").toggle('normal');   
                });
            });
            $("#vraag3").click(function(){
                $("#antwoord3").toggle('normal');
                $("#antwoord3").click(function(){
                    $("#antwoord3").toggle('normal');   
                });
            });
            $("#vraag4").click(function(){
                $("#antwoord4").toggle('normal');
                $("#antwoord4").click(function(){
                    $("#antwoord4").toggle('normal');   
                });

            });
            $("#vraag5").click(function(){
                $("#antwoord5").toggle('normal');
                $("#antwoord5").click(function(){
                    $("#antwoord5").toggle('normal');   
                });                 
            });
        });

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hidden{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="vraag1"> vraag 1 </p>
    <p class="hidden" id="antwoord1"> antwoord1 </p>
    <p id="vraag2"> vraag 2 </p>
    <p class="hidden" id="antwoord2"> antwoord2 </p>
    <p id="vraag3"> vraag 3 </p>
    <p class="hidden" id="antwoord3"> antwoord3 </p>
    <p id="vraag4"> vraag 4 </p>
    <p class="hidden" id="antwoord4"> antwoord4 </p>
    <p id="vraag5"> vraag 5 </p>
    <p class="hidden" id="antwoord5"> antwoord5 </p>
</body>
</hmtl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should change your HTML to use classes instead of (or in addition to) ids:

```
<p class="vraag"> vraag 1 </p>
<p class="hidden antwoord"> antwoord1 </p>
<p class="vraag"> vraag 2 </p>
<p class="hidden antwoord"> antwoord2 </p>
```

Then you rewrite the click event handler to take advantage of the classes and the structure of your HTML:

```
$(".vraag").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".antwoord").toggle('normal');
});
```

I am not setting up a `click` handler for `.antwoord` above because that would end up setting an *additional* click handler every time you click on the `.vraag` (you can put an `alert` inside your own code to see what I mean).

Instead of this, we can just set up the return-to-normal toggle just once for `.antwoord` as we did for `.vraag`:

```
$(".antwoord").click(function(){
    $(this).toggle('normal');   
});
```

That's all -- two minimal event handlers will now take care of any amount of content.

Comment: Thx! this was very helpfull! But could you explain me, why it doesnt toggle all the <p> with the class "antwoord" and "vraag"?

Comment: @KevinvanHengst: You mean why it doesn't toggle all of them when you click one? Because the code operates on `$(this)` or the next-to-this element. It could be changed to toggle everything, but I followed your original code.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for a way to write this alot shorter!

The shortest code I see, **without any modification on your current HTML code**, is :

```
$('p').click(function(){
    $(this).next().hasClass('hidden') ? $(this).next().toggle('normal') : $(this).toggle('normal');
});
```

Please note that my answer **is not meant to be the most adapted**, and should not be used as is on your website.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sDrqH/) for a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

use attribute selector with `^` this gets all the element begining with the given string
and call seperate click event for `antwoord` outside(not inside the click event of `vraag`) keeping it inside you need additional click event for vraag for it to work...

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("p[id^='vraag']").click(function(){
            $(this).next('p').toggle('normal');

        });
        $("p[id^='antwoord']").click(function(){
                $(this).toggle('normal');   
            });
  });
```